# Function to send email, refactored based on SOLID principles

Tags: c#, object-oriented, comparative-review, email

I have the below method that is responsible for generating and sending a `MailMessage` using a `SmtpClient` object:

```
public static void SendEmail(
    string subject, 
    string body, 
    bool isBodyHtml, 
    List<string> emails, 
    List<string> ccs = null)
{
    if (emails == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("emails");
    }
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml
    };
    foreach (string email in emails)
    {
        message.To.Add(email);
    }
    if (ccs != null)
    {
        foreach (string cc in ccs)
        {
            message.CC.Add(cc);
        }
    }
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
    {
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    };
    client.Send(message);
}
```

But recently I've been reading more on S.O.L.I.D and principles of OOP design, so I thought to refactor this method, and compartmentalize it more.

Am I on the right track with my refactor? Are there ways to make my code more modular/testable?

Here's my refactored code:

```
private static MailMessage CreateMailMessage(
    string subject, 
    string body, 
    bool isBodyHtml, 
    List<string> emails, 
    List<string> ccs = null)
{
    if (emails == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("emails");
    }
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml
    };
    foreach (string email in emails)
    {
        message.To.Add(email);
    }
    if (ccs != null)
    {
        foreach (string cc in ccs)
        {
            message.CC.Add(cc);
        }
    }
    return message;
}

private static SmtpClient CreateSmtpClient(
    bool enableSsl, 
    SmtpDeliveryMethod deliveryMethod)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
    {
        EnableSsl = enableSsl,
        DeliveryMethod = deliveryMethod
    };
    return client;
}
```

And here's the method responsible for calling the above two and sending the email:

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> emails, List<string> ccs = null)
{
    using (MailMessage message = CreateMailMessage(subject, body, true, emails, ccs))
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = CreateSmtpClient(true, SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network))
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a custom datatype containing your mail? Now you have to pass around a subject, body, ccs (should be split into ccs & bccs), etc. Should save you a lot of validation as well, eventually.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell if an object is SOLID just from 2 functions, it would be better if the entire class were included.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The class these two methods are contained in is a general purpose utilities class, containing a hodgepodge of static utility methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd still say that you should break apart the mail message and SMTP client into separate classes for the "Single responsibility principle". In specific:

> A class should only have a single responsibility, that is, only changes to one part of the software's specification should be able to affect the specification of the class.

This is usually where you have a `MailFactory` and a `SmtpClientFactory` that are injected into the class that actually does the sending (`MailSender`). The injection (by abstract, so interfaces) would be set into the `MailSender` to fulfill the "Dependency inversion principle"

> One should "depend upon abstractions, [not] concretions."

*Side Note*

This would also let you reduce `MailFactory.CreateMailMessage` to `MailFactory.Create` (and `SmtpClientFactory.CreateSmtpClient` to `SmtpClientFactory.Create`) but that isn't directly related to SOLID. You can get why in various API naming conventions, but the short answer is that it would be redundant.

*Expansion*

A reason for this is when you do unit testing. We have an abstract mail client that just sticks messages into an in-memory list in the order they are sent. That way, we can inject it into the sender as `ISmtpClientFactory` and the rest of the code still works, not knowing that we have taken out the entire implementation of the sending for testing.

*Edit 2*

You also want to avoid `static` in general. It is implied by "injecting" but I figured I'd clarify that. Create factory instances and pass them in. That way you can swap them out.